# could not get all matching items from many to many relationship tables using group by

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, inner-join

Following is the sql code for my scenario. and this is the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d94bef/2)

```
CREATE TABLE `hotels` (
  `hotel_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`hotel_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `features_list` (
  `feature_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `feature` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`feature_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `hotels_features` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `hotel_id` INT(11) NULL,
  `feature_id` INT(11) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `hotels_features`(`hotel_id`, `feature_id`) VALUES (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3), (3,1), (3,2);
INSERT INTO `hotels`(`name`) VALUES ('test1'), ('test2'), ('test3');
INSERT INTO `features_list`(`feature`) VALUES ('feature1'), ('feature2'), ('feature3');
```

This is the SQL Query I am using

```
SELECT hotels.hotel_id, hotels.name, features_list.feature
FROM hotels
LEFT JOIN hotels_features
ON hotels.hotel_id = hotels_features.hotel_id
INNER JOIN features_list
ON hotels_features.feature_id = features_list.feature_id
GROUP BY hotels.hotel_id
```

But from this query I am getting a result as this, As you see in this only feature1 is there. but I need to show all the features that a hotel is having. if I remove GROUP BY  hotels.hotel_id it is repeating the hotels. can some one help me on this. Thank You.

```
| HOTEL_ID |  NAME |  FEATURE |
|----------|-------|----------|
|        1 | test1 | feature1 |
|        2 | test2 | feature1 |
|        3 | test3 | feature1 |
```

My Expected result is like this

```
| HOTEL_ID |  NAME |  FEATURE                   |
|----------|-------|----------------------------|
|        1 | test1 | feature1 feature2 feature3 |
|        2 | test2 | feature1 feature2 feature3 |
|        3 | test3 | feature1 feature2  |
```

Comment: What would be the expected output from the sample data ?

Comment: What is your expacted result?

Comment: `INSERT INTO `features_list`(`feature`) VALUES ('feature1'), ('feature1'), ('feature1');` you are adding the feature name same across this table and hence you are getting the same name repeated. And `group by` clause without any aggregate function is of almost no use.

Comment: I updated the question. sorry for my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT` to get a comma-separated list of all the features:

```
SELECT hotels.hotel_id, hotels.name, GROUP_CONCAT(features_list.feature) AS features
FROM hotels
LEFT JOIN hotels_features
ON hotels.hotel_id = hotels_features.hotel_id
LEFT JOIN features_list
ON hotels_features.feature_id = features_list.feature_id
GROUP BY hotels.hotel_id
```

Also, since you're using `LEFT JOIN` to get the `hotels_features`, you need to use `LEFT_JOIN` with `features_list` as well. Otherwise, when you have a hotel with no features, `hotels_features.feature_id` will be `NULL`, and that won't match `features_list.feature_id`, and that will prevent the row from being put into the result.